# Rails 7 Session Data Not Persisting Heroku

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, heroku

I'm creating a full stack project using a React frontend/Rails 7 backend, but I cannot login using my heroku-deployed backend. Everything works in dev.In production, I can create a user, see them in the database, I can login and successfully get redirected, but I don't stay logged in.

```
def login!
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
end
```

After that, the user is supposed to get redirected to a homepage.

When the redirect happens, the homepage calls the api to see if the user is authorized using:

```
def logged_in?
     !!session[:user_id]
end
```

But the session is empty.

Here is my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.find_by(username: session_params[:username])
      
        if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
          login!
          render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: @user
          }
        else
          render json: { 
            status: 401,
            errors: ['Incorrect username or password, please try again.']
          }
        end
    end
    def is_logged_in?
        if logged_in? && current_user
          render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: current_user
          }
        else
          render json: {
            logged_in: false,
            message: 'no such user'
          }
        end
    end
    def destroy
          logout!
          render json: {
            status: 200,
            logged_out: true
          }
    end
    private
    def session_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

And here is my application.rb

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Wms
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 7.0

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.

  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
    end
  end


   config.api_only = true

   # Adding back cookies and session middleware
   config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
   config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore

   # Use SameSite=Strict for all cookies to help protect against CSRF
   config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :strict
 

  end
end
```

I've spent weeks trying to figure this out and am in desperate need of help. Can anyone take a look?

My backend is deployed at: https://floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this topic on Heroku ->
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

Also, you can try this option in your `production.rb`
`config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :none`

But I would say that it's better to manage sessions with JWT or some access token rather than putting it into cookies